# less/more Information is not working properly(profile Page)

Tags: discussion, profile-page

i faced one issue. When i click into **more info link** in profile page then it's not working properly some times. I used `chrome v40.0`.

Below snap shot:

[image]

Comment: Probably collateral damage from rolling out the [new profile/activity page design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features).

Comment: What OS are you on? I can't repro this.

Comment: I am on Windows 7. and this occurred some times.